# SQL recursive query on self referencing table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, hierarchical-data

Lets assume I have this sample data:

```
| Name     | ID | PARENT_ID |
-----------------------------
| a1       | 1  | null      |
| b2       | 2  | null      |
| c3       | 3  | null      |
| a1.d4    | 4  | 1         |
| a1.e5    | 5  | 1         |
| a1.d4.f6 | 6  | 4         |
| a1.d4.g7 | 7  | 4         |
| a1.e5.h8 | 8  | 5         |
| a2.i9    | 9  | 2         |
| a2.i9.j10| 10 | 9         |
```

I would like to select all records start from accountId = 1, so the expected result would be:

```
| Name     | ID | PARENT_NAME | PARENT_ID | 
-------------------------------------------
| a1       | 1  | null        | null      |
| a1.d4    | 4  | a1          | 1         |
| a1.e5    | 5  | a1          | 1         |
| a1.d4.f6 | 6  | a1.d4       | 4         |
| a1.d4.g7 | 7  | a1.d4       | 4         |
| a1.e5.h8 | 8  | a1.e5       | 5         |
```

I am currently able to make the recursive select, but then I can't access the data from the parent reference, hence I can't return parent_name. The code I'm using is (adapted to the simplistic example):

```
SELECT id, parent_id, name
FROM tbl 
  START WITH id = 1 
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
```

What SQL should I be using to the mentioned above retrieval?

*Additional key words for future seekers: SQL to select hierarchical data represented by parent keys in same table*

Comment: Call me stubborn, but I'm still not convinced that the accepted answer it's the best performant. Could you post how suggested query's perform on your data?

Comment: @Samuel I have accepted OMG answer because of it's simplicity and for it's fit for this scenario requirements. I am still not convinced that subquries perform better then joins: based on @OMG comment regarding tkprof (I \\assume\\ he **did** run the tests) I think it's safe to estimate that the proposed solution is the correct one. I currently do not have enough test data to produce meaningful results (<50 records). It's perfectly fine that you do not accept that your answer is not the correct one. I don't think you should. I should mention that I am in no way an Oracle DBA expert.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use:

```
    SELECT t1.id, 
           t1.parent_id, 
           t1.name,
           t2.name AS parent_name,
           t2.id AS parent_id
      FROM tbl t1
 LEFT JOIN tbl t2 ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
START WITH t1.id = 1 
CONNECT BY PRIOR t1.id = t1.parent_id
```

Comment: I think that query is doing unnecessary work joining with itself too early. Don't you think?

Comment: The OP lists columns that should return NULL, which the `LEFT JOIN` does - which is not unnecessary work either.

Comment: VERY GOOD, I'm happy. Thank you :). 

Please note for current version you would get "SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined", to fix this the SQL needs to be tweaked to read:

START WITH t1.id = 1 
CONNECT BY PRIOR t1.id = t1.parent_id

Comment: @Maxim: Yeah, I realized after the 5 min mark that I missed the table aliases.  Corrected.

Comment: What happens if there's a circle in the graph? Will the SELECT fail, or will it loop forever?

Answer (score 16):

What about using PRIOR,

so

```
SELECT id, parent_id, PRIOR name
   FROM tbl 
START WITH id = 1 
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id`
```

or if you want to get the root name

```
SELECT id, parent_id, CONNECT_BY_ROOT name
   FROM tbl 
START WITH id = 1 
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
```

Answer (score 11):

Using the new nested query syntax

```
with q(name, id, parent_id, parent_name) as (
    select 
      t1.name, t1.id, 
      null as parent_id, null as parent_name 
    from t1
    where t1.id = 1
  union all
    select 
      t1.name, t1.id, 
      q.id as parent_id, q.name as parent_name 
    from t1, q
    where t1.parent_id = q.id
)
select * from q
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do this?

```
SELECT id, parent_id, name, 
 (select Name from tbl where id = t.parent_id) parent_name
FROM tbl t start with id = 1 CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
```

**Edit**
Another option based on OMG's one (but I think that will perform equally):

```
select 
           t1.id, 
           t1.parent_id, 
           t1.name,
           t2.name AS parent_name,
           t2.id AS parent_id
from 
    (select id, parent_id, name
    from tbl
    start with id = 1 
    connect by prior id = parent_id) t1
    left join
    tbl t2 on t2.id = t1.parent_id
```

Comment: YES, but as far as I understand this is inefficient because that causes the RDBMS to make additional inner query for each returned result?

Comment: @Maxim: You are correct - that is a correlated subquery, that will execute once for every row returned.  While it works, it is the least efficient means available.

Comment: @OMG I don't think so. The optimizer is clever enough to infer a join by itself. Look at the explain plan.

Comment: @Samuel: Can you please explain your rational for using the inner select in this situation?

Comment: @OMG Sorry but I can't agree. Scalar subquerys are a valid alternative to outer join's, and usually perform faster. Look at this http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/scalar_subqueries.html

Comment: @Maxim The inner select is for restricting the join only those rows that are going to be affected for the left join. It's faster to do the more restrictive "connect by" first and then the left join.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little on the cumbersome side, but I believe this should work (without the extra join).  This assumes that you can choose a character that will never appear in the field in question, to act as a separator.

You can do it without nesting the select, but I find this a little cleaner that having four references to SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH.

```
select id, 
       parent_id, 
       case 
         when lvl <> 1 
         then substr(name_path,
                     instr(name_path,'|',1,lvl-1)+1,
                     instr(name_path,'|',1,lvl)
                      -instr(name_path,'|',1,lvl-1)-1) 
         end as name 
from (
  SELECT id, parent_id, sys_connect_by_path(name,'|') as name_path, level as lvl
  FROM tbl 
  START WITH id = 1 
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id)
```