# Complex SQL Query: Select like tree traversal

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, db2

Consider the following `(1:N)` relationship:

`[entity: user] <------ rid key ------> [entity: rid]`.

consider the data in both tables as:

```
select * from user;
user-id        rid-key
a-basa         a
b-basa         b
a.a-basa       a.a   
a.b-basa       a.b
a.a.a-basa     a.a.a
a.a.b-basa     a.a.b
a.b.a-basa     a.b.a
a.b.b-basa     a.b.b
a.b.b.a-basa   a.b.b.a
a.b.b.b-basa   a.b.b.b



select * from rid;

rid-key    parent-rid    enabled
a            null        true
b            null        true
a.a          a           true 
a.b          a           false
a.a.a        a.a         true
a.b.a        a.b         true
a.b.b        a.b         true
a.b.b.a      a.b.b       true
......
n rows
```

I need to design a single query (not stored procedure) which will input a `user-id`, and the following facts are considered:

If an user is given access to a `rid`, then it can also access the `parent rid` of the `rid` given - the `rid` itself is enabled `(enabled = true).`

This should continue till we reach the `root rid`, ie. `parent rid` property is `null`.

In above example, the list of accessible rid for the user `'a.b.b.a-basa'` will be`:`

```
a.b.b.a
a.b.b
a.b
```

and for `a.a.a-basa`:

```
a.a.a
a.a
a
```

can we get this list using a single query? Any sql vendor is fine.

Comment: +1 for the question, with a loop this would have been...:) much easier, but anyway you need a query...

Comment: is the number of levels known? If not, I do not believe it will be possible, as SQL does not support recursion.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319284/sql-recursive-query-on-self-refrencing-table-oracle ?

Comment: @cha: SQL (the language) supports recursion. MySQL implementation of SQL does not (only through procedures and functions).

Comment: And with this particular design, one doesn't even need a recursive query. It can be done with a simple one that would work in all DBMS.

Comment: thanks guys for the comments. I learnt something new. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

Comment: @ypercube: you should add an answer showing that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several models for Hierarchical data. Most models (like the **Adjacency List**) require some sort of recursion for some queries. With your design that uses the **Materialized Path** model, what you want is possible without a recursive query.

Tested in MySQL (that has no recursive queries), at **[SQL-fiddle test-mysql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/355e0/6)**. It can be easily converted for other DBMS, if you modify the string concatenation part:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*)-1 AS steps_up,
     rid2.rid_key AS ancestor_rid_key
FROM 
    u2 
  JOIN
    rid 
      ON u2.rid_key = rid.rid_key
      OR u2.rid_key LIKE CONCAT(rid.rid_key, '.%')
  JOIN
    rid AS rid2 
      ON rid.rid_key = rid2.rid_key
      OR rid.rid_key LIKE CONCAT(rid2.rid_key, '.%')
WHERE
    u2.userid = 'basa'
  AND
    u2.rid_key = 'a.b.b.a' 
GROUP BY 
    rid2.rid_key, rid2.enabled 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) + (rid2.enabled = 'true') 
  = SUM(rid.enabled = 'true') + 1 ;
```

It uses this view, which is not strictly needed but it shows that the `user.user_id` is storing data that you already have in the `rid_key` column.

```
CREATE VIEW u2 AS
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_id, '-', -1) AS userid
  , rid_key
FROM user ;
```

One more note is that the above query does not use the `parent_rid` column at all. And that I'm sure it can be further improved.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can achieve this using a hierarhical query. Search for CONNECT BY or have a look at this [article](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html).

Answer (score 1):

This should get the ball rolling for you.
The answer works on SQL Server 2005 onwards

```
DECLARE @UsersRIDkey VARCHAR(10) = 'a.a.a'
;WITH UserCTE (userid, ridkey) AS
(
    SELECT 'a-basa',         'a'        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b-basa',         'b'        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.a-basa',       'a.a'      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.b-basa',       'a.b'      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.a.a-basa',     'a.a.a'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.a.b-basa',     'a.a.b'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.b.a-basa',     'a.b.a'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.b.b-basa',     'a.b.b'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.b.b.a-basa',   'a.b.b.a'  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.b.b.b-basa',   'a.b.b.b'  
)
,RidCTE (ridkey, parentrid,    isenabled) AS
(
    SELECT 'a',            null,        1   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b',            null,        1   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.a',          'a',         1   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.b',          'a',         0   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.a.a',        'a.a',       1   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.b.a',        'a.b',       1   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.b.b',        'a.b',       1   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.b.b.a',      'a.b.b',     1   
)
,RidHierarchyCTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM RidCTE
    WHERE ridkey = @UsersRIDkey
    UNION ALL
    SELECT R.ridkey, R.parentrid, R.isenabled
    FROM RidHierarchyCTE    H
    JOIN RidCTE             R ON R.ridkey = H.parentrid
)
SELECT ridkey
FROM RidHierarchyCTE
```

Comment: Should work for PostgreSQL and DB2 as well (apart from the variable definition). Btw: you should get used to putting the statement terminator (`;`) where it belongs: at the end: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Answer (score 1):

Oracle solution:

```
SQL> select u.user_id, r.rid_key, r.parent_rid, r.enabled
  2    from users u
  3         inner join rid r
  4                 on r.rid_key = u.rid_key
  5   start with u.user_id = 'a.a.a-basa'
  6   connect by prior r.parent_rid = r.rid_key and prior enabled = 'true'
  7  /

USER_ID      RID_KEY PAREN ENABL
------------ ------- ----- -----
a.a.a-basa   a.a.a   a.a   true
a.a-basa     a.a     a     true
a-basa       a       null  true

SQL> select u.user_id, r.rid_key, r.parent_rid, r.enabled
  2    from users u
  3         inner join rid r
  4                 on r.rid_key = u.rid_key
  5   start with u.user_id = 'a.b.b.a-basa'
  6   connect by prior r.parent_rid = r.rid_key and prior enabled = 'true'
  7  /

USER_ID      RID_KEY PAREN ENABL
------------ ------- ----- -----
a.b.b.a-basa a.b.b.a a.b.b true
a.b.b-basa   a.b.b   a.b   true
a.b-basa     a.b     a     false
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d529f/1