# Query for child/parent relationship from one table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I have a parent and child on the same table how can I get the child parent relation where child name = xyz?

```
SELECT C.RQ_REQ_ID, C.RQ_FATHER_ID, C.RQ_REQ_NAME
FROM REQ C, REQ P
WHERE C.RQ_FATHER_ID =+ P.RQ_REQ_ID AND P.RQ_REQ_NAME = 'XYZ'
```

result I want

```
RQ_REQ_ID        RQ_FATHER_ID      RQ_REQ_NAME
------------------------------------------------------
0                 -1               Requirement
1                 0                EP Release
363               1                UAT
364               363              2013
438               364              XYZ
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please show the table structure and sample table data, and database you are using.

Comment: Do you realize that your sample results include an endless loop? (`0` and `1` are parents of each other)

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: Oracle with sql navigator or I can use TOAD

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319284/sql-recursive-query-on-self-refrencing-table-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks like you use Oracle, so this recursive query should work:

```
SELECT rq_req_id, rq_father_id, rq_req_name
  FROM req
CONNECT BY rq_req_id = PRIOR rq_father_id
START WITH rq_req_name = 'XYZ';
```