# Oracle SQL recursive query to find parent of level one

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

suppose i have a table service :

```
     Name      | ID | PARENT_ID | LEVEL | 
------------------------------------------- 
 s1            | 1  | null      | 0     | 
 s2            | 2  | 1         | 1     | 
 s3            | 3  | 1         | 2     |      
 s4            | 4  | 2         | 2     | 
 s5            | 5  | 3         | 3     | 
 s6            | 6  | 4         | 3     |
```

and i want to get the parent of level 1 for s6(id=6) which should return s2 , is there a way to make a recursive query until a level is reached ?

Comment: did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319284/sql-recursive-query-on-self-refrencing-table-oracle

Comment: @danisius difference here is that i have a level column which can be any number and the query has to go up until the specified level is reached

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You can go UP the tree instead of going down - from leaf (id = 6) to root (which in this reverse case itself would be a leaf, `connect_by_isleaf = 1`), and take a "parent" of that leaf using `prior` operator.</strike>

**upd**: Misunderstood your requirement about `LEVEL` (in Oracle hierarchical queries it is a dynamic pseudocolumn specifying hierarchical depth of a row). If you want to limit your result set to rows with a specific value of your custom pre-populated `LEVEL` column - you can just add it to `where` condition.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5fad/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("NAME" varchar2(2), "ID" int, "PARENT_ID" int, "LVL" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t ("NAME", "ID", "PARENT_ID", "LVL")
         VALUES ('s1', 1, NULL, 0)
    INTO t ("NAME", "ID", "PARENT_ID", "LVL")
         VALUES ('s2', 2, 1, 1)
    INTO t ("NAME", "ID", "PARENT_ID", "LVL")
         VALUES ('s3', 3, 1, 2)
    INTO t ("NAME", "ID", "PARENT_ID", "LVL")
         VALUES ('s4', 4, 2, 2)
    INTO t ("NAME", "ID", "PARENT_ID", "LVL")
         VALUES ('s5', 5, 3, 3)
    INTO t ("NAME", "ID", "PARENT_ID", "LVL")
         VALUES ('s6', 6, 4, 3)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id as id, name as name from t
where lvl = 1
connect by  id = prior parent_id
  start with id = 6
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5fad/6/0)**:

```
| ID | NAME |
|----|------|
|  2 |   s2 |
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with a hierarchical query:

```
create table tq84_h (
  id number,
  parent_id number,
  level_    number
);

insert into tq84_h values (1, null, 0);
insert into tq84_h values (2, 1   , 1);
insert into tq84_h values (3, 1   , 2);
insert into tq84_h values (4, 2   , 2);
insert into tq84_h values (5, 3   , 3);
insert into tq84_h values (6, 4   , 3);

select 
  parent_id
from
  tq84_h
where
  level_ = 2
start with
  id = 6
connect by
  prior parent_id = id and
  level_>1
;
```