# Variable levels of recursive self join - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have the following table:

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| ID | COMPANY | PARENT_COMPANY |
+----+---------+----------------+
|  1 | A       | X              |
|  2 | B       | Y              |
|  3 | C       | Z              |
|  4 | D       | A              |
|  5 | E       | D              |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to retrieve the a certain company and all descendants regardless how many they are and how many levels they expand.

For example, the company `A` has the child `D` which in turn has the child `E` and so forth. I want to show all these companies in one column.

I tired self-join, but I think it the number of levels is fixed. I checked the ORACLE related questions here, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319284/sql-recursive-query-on-self-refrencing-table-oracle) but the number of levels is restricted.

Comment: The linked question *is* the answer to your problem. `connect by` can handle an unlimited number of levels.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yup, that's right, I was not totally aware of `connect by` capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Using WITH clause:

```
WITH rt (
    COMPANY,
    CHILD_COMPANY
) AS (
    SELECT
        t.COMPANY,
        t.COMPANY AS CHILD_COMPANY
    FROM
        Test t
    WHERE
        t.COMPANY = 'A' /* selected company */
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        rt.COMPANY,
        t.COMPANY AS CHILD_COMPANY
    FROM
        rt
    JOIN
        Test t
    ON
        rt.CHILD_COMPANY = t.PARENT_COMPANY
)
SELECT
    rt.COMPANY,
    LISTAGG(rt.CHILD_COMPANY, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rt.CHILD_COMPANY) AS DESCENDANTS
FROM
    rt
WHERE
    rt.COMPANY <> rt.CHILD_COMPANY  /* exclude self-match */
GROUP BY
    rt.COMPANY;
```