# Oracle hierarchical query select records along path

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Suppose the company hierarchy is like this:

```
King
-> John
  -> Jack
    -> Chris
    -> Sean
  -> April
-> Jerry
  -> Tom
```

Given an ancestor e.g. `King`, and a `subordinate`, e.g. Chris, is it possible to select all records along the path `/King/John/Jack/Chris` in one query? i.e. the query will return 4 records - `King, John, Jack and Chris`?

Table structure:
Employee_Name Employee_ID Manager_ID

Manager_ID references to Employee_ID

Comment: Yes it's possible. You should start from `Chris` and select all parents. Table definition and sample data wold be helpful. [I think you can start here ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319284/sql-recursive-query-on-self-refrencing-table-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as
(
    select 'King' as Employee_Name,  1 as Employee_ID, -1 as Manager_ID from dual union all
    select 'John' as Employee_Name,  2 as Employee_ID, 1 as Manager_ID from dual union all
    select 'Jack' as Employee_Name,  3 as Employee_ID, 2 as Manager_ID from dual union all
    select 'Chris' as Employee_Name, 4  as Employee_ID, 3 as Manager_ID from dual union all
    select 'Sean' as Employee_Name,  5 as Employee_ID, 3 as Manager_ID from dual union all
    select 'April' as Employee_Name,  6 as Employee_ID, 2 as Manager_ID from dual union all
    select 'Jerry' as Employee_Name, 7  as Employee_ID, 1 as Manager_ID from dual union all
    select 'Tom' as Employee_Name, 8  as Employee_ID, 7 as Manager_ID from dual
)
select Employee_Name 
 from t
connect by prior Manager_ID = Employee_ID
start with Employee_Name = 'Chris'
order by level desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your table structure is. In case you store it as paths then the below should work. The query supports multiple records with Chris. It will select all of them.

```
with test as
  (
  select 1 id, '/King/John/Jack/Chris' str from dual union all
  select 2 id, '/King/John/Jack/April' str from dual union all
  select 3 id, '/King/John/Jack/Sean' str from dual union all
  select 4 id, '/King/Jerry/Tom' str from dual
)
   select id,
          str,
         regexp_substr (str, '[^/]+', 1, rn) split,
          rn
    from test 
    cross
    join (select rownum rn
            from (select max (length (regexp_replace (str, '[^/]+'))) + 1 mx
                    from test
                )
       connect by level <= mx
         ) A
   where regexp_substr (str, '[^/]+', 1, rn) is not null
    and instr(str, 'Chris') > 0 
   order by id, rn
 ;
```

Here is an example in SQL Fiddle

[**Example in SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/4256/0)

The trick is cross join that creates multiple rows for each row in main table.

```
ID  STR SPLIT   RN
1   /King/John/Jack/Chris   King    1
1   /King/John/Jack/Chris   John    2
1   /King/John/Jack/Chris   Jack    3
1   /King/John/Jack/Chris   Chris   4
```