# How to attach a callback on a recursively generated <select> dropdown?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I'm trying to implement chained dependent dropdown combobox selection, so you start with one combobox for main category and once you select main category, another `<select>` appears to select a subcategory, and so on until the innermost (most specific) category is selected. The code I have currently only works for one subcategory (direct children), how can I make it work for other levels too? So, I need to attach an onChange callback to a newly created `<select>` somehow.

This is jQuery code in my Django template:

```
{% extends 'pages/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Create a product</h1>
<form method='POST' id='productForm' data-products-url="{% url 'products:ajax_load_categories' %}">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("select").change(function () {
      var url = $("#productForm").attr("data-products-url");
      var categoryId = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({                       
        url: url,                    
        data: {
          'category': categoryId
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#productForm").append(data);
        }
      });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my view:

```
def load_categories(request):
    category_id = request.GET.get('category')
    subcategories = Category.objects.get(id=category_id).get_children()
    return render(request, 'products/category_dropdown_list_options.html', {'subcategories': subcategories})
```

`products/category_dropdown_list_options.html`

```
<select id="select_{{ subcategories.first.get_level }}">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
        <option value="{{ subcategory.pk }}">{{ subcategory.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
app_name = 'products'
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', product_create_view, name='product-create'),
    path('ajax/load-categories/', load_categories, name='ajax_load_categories')
]
```

Here is my Category model as per request:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('parent', 'slug',))
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_slug_list(self):
        ancestors = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
        slugs = [ancestor.slug for ancestor in ancestors]
        new_slugs = []
        for idx, ancestor in enumerate(slugs, 1):
            new_slugs.append('/'.join(slugs[:idx]))
        return new_slugs

    def get_recursive_product_count(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category__in=self.get_descendants(include_self=True)).count()
```

Comment: +1 for an excellent question!  This is eerily similar to a problem I had that used a recursive `Category` model (although I took a different approach).  I might end up implementing your idea myself.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170974/how-do-i-order-a-model-by-parent-category-in-django) is the approach I ended up taking, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to turn your jQuery ajax script into a function, then call it *recursively*, like this:

```
<script>
    var $r_ = function() {
        var url = $("#productForm").attr("data-products-url");
        var categoryId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({                       
          url: url,                    
          data: {
            'category': categoryId
          },
          success: function (data) {
            if (data != 'leaf_node') {
              $("#productForm").append(data);
            }
            $('select').change($r_);
          }
        });

    } //end of $r_

    $('select').change($r_);
</script>
```

### Update

If you take a look at the `get_children` method of the `MPTT` model, you'll see that it checks whether or not the instance has any children, and returns `None` if it doesn't.

Add a `None` check in your view, then add a different response when you've reached a *leaf node*:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def load_categories(request):
    category_id = request.GET.get('category')
    subcategories = Category.objects.get(id=category_id).get_children()
    if subcategories:
        return render(request, 'products/category_dropdown_list_options.html', {'subcategories': subcategories})

    return HttpResponse('leaf_node')
```

Then add a check for leaf nodes in your ajax call (see above).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, it was very helpful. You have a couple of minor mistakes, on line 15 the `(` is redundant, and on the next line `}` is extra. On one hand this kind of works, on the other hand it kind of doesn't, because it will create a select when I reach the innermost subcategory. So, if there is Books -> Textbooks -> Primary school, once Primary school is selected, another unnecessary `<select>` will be created. Might you know how to fix that? Thanks once again.

Comment: @dedmauz69 yeah I think that'll be an easy fix, but I need to see your `Category` model.

Comment: You just need to check whether or not the data gotten in `success` has any children, and if they don't, don't add the listener.

Comment: I'm using `django-mptt` and a MPTTModel has a very handy method, `is_leaf_node()`, the thing is how to use it in this scenario. I've updated the question to include my Category model.

Comment: @dedmauz69 I'm working on an update, but just noticed you are using `render` in your view.  Is that view exclusively for ajax requests?  If so, you are probably better off just using `HttpResponse` or `JsonResponse`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a tonne!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200132/discussion-between-dedmauz69-and-caleb-goodman).